# Can I develop Microsoft Dynamics 365 on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am using `Ubuntu 18.04` and I would like to develop a plugin for `Microsoft Dynamics 365`.

For example I know that `IOS` development can only be developed using apple products and cannot be developed on `Ubuntu` and I'm wondering if it's the same for `Microsoft Dynamics 365`?

I have watched several tutorial videos such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OROfBriR_YU although I still do not know if I can develop `Microsoft Dynamics 365` on `Ubuntu` or if I need a `Windows` OS.

I can see that `Visual Studio` can be downloaded for `Ubuntu` here: https://code.visualstudio.com/download but before I start I want to make sure that I can install and run all other tools necessary to develop a plugin for `Microsoft Dynamics 365`.

Is there anything (tools, platforms) in the development process that I would not be able to use, install in `Ubuntu`?

Answer (score 2):

That download is Visual Studio Code, which is Microsoft's cross-platform coding tool/text editor. Regular [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) is the full IDE.

The problem with writing a plugin for Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement (now known as the Common Data Service or CDS) is that the [SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/) requires the full [.NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/supported-customizations#support-for-net-framework-versions), which is Windows-only.

Microsoft has said that they're working on a version of the SDK that works with .NET Core, but as far as I know it has yet to arrive.
On the bright side, Microsoft has announced that they will be converging the entire .NET platform into .NET 5 in November 2020, so that should be the latest that full CDS SDK development goes cross-platform (assuming that Microsoft hits its target date.)

.NET Core is cross-platform. You could use Visual Studio Code on Linux to write a console app in .NET Core 3.0 that accesses the CDS via its [WebAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/overview). However, for a plugin the SDK remains the way to go.

UPDATE: Microsoft has released an [ALPHA version](https://colinvermander.com/2020/02/13/net-core-cds-sdk-alpha-availability/) of the CDS SDK that's compatible with .NET Core 3.0 and 3.1.